# Application exchanging data between Android and Spring service

Tags: java, android, spring

I need to create system, which can exchange data between Spring. In Android app, i have form, which I need to pass to the Spring service, then process the data, and send the answer back to the Android app. Could you tell me, what tools I should use, to make communication between Spring and Android (any tutorials or something)? Is REST good for something like that?

Comment: please be more specific while formulating your question. Now it's too broad

Comment: I'm looking for answer, how could I connect Android application and Spring web service, to exchange data?

Comment: Use `volley` or `Retrofit` for pushing data into web service, it might be spring..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use REST to do it.

You will need to send/receive http request/response from your app. You can do it manually (see google [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)) or you can use a library like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

There are a lot of tutorials on the internet, but maybe you will love the one from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853) (check lesson 2)